# Why there is no direct connection between the data bus and the accumulater register

Tags: computer-architecture

In the data bus all the registers are connected in and out with the data bus but the AC don't have it only out also the memory don't have a direct connection with it ?
Please explain if you know

Answer (score 1):

The answer as in many cases: Someone thought it was a good idea.

Someone may have evaluated cost and benefits and may have decided that the benefits were not worth the cost.